# vb.net Move between two form with option

Tags: vb.net, forms

at first i am sorry for my weak english but i will try my best to explain my issue 
i am new in programming so i got idea but i don't know if can be happen or not
the idea is , i have 2 form separated each form have there cods , but i want to add button in form one its open the second form, to add thing to the second one , but i need to return to first form when i close the second form
can i do something like that ??
for clarification the second form i can open it from other ways and have own function and the first form too

UPDATING !!! 
at first thank for all your answers and not useful vote ,second yes i am new but not that much i know how to use `formname.show()` and `formname.close()` etc..... ,the issue not about usual ways to open and close forms, for example in form one i input information about user one of the option is where he live, the country choosing from dropbox ,next to the dropbox there button named add new country the button open new form to add new country when i add new country and closed the form back to the first form ,  and just to be know there button in the third form (setting) to open the form add new country ,IN SHORT WORD I DON'T NEED TO OPEN THE FIRST FORM EVERY TIME I CLOSE THE SECOND ONE , ONLY RETURN TO THE FIRST FORM IF I CAME FROM THE BUTTON THAT I CLICKED IN FORM ONE

Comment: This should get you started [YouTube Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AGG_LnCQFEA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put this on action

`formname.show()` 'for opening a new form
`formname.close()` 'for opening closing the form
`formname.showdialog()` 'Where you cant click the main form``

Comment: one more thing if you don't mind how i can add code when the dialog closing, are there event to write the code. i need to refresh the combobox

Comment: add a code when dialog is closing? what do you mean? after you close the form then something will popup after?

Comment: no ,nothing popup after , just i need to refresh the value of the combobox in the first form with the new value that i add in the second form , i mean something like Disposed event but when i close the dialog that i opened by ` SecondForm.showdialog() `

Comment: try this combobox.text = " " or combobox.text=nothing or combobox.reset()

Comment: its done i did recalled the function that load the combobox in the second FormClosing event , and now all work fine

Answer (score 0):

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

'show form 2

Form2.Show()

'move text from one form to another

Form2.TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text

End Sub